# Is it possible to block git pulls/fetches?

Tags: git, jenkins, rebase

in our project we have a jenkins job running from a remote master branch. Developers often rebase from this remote master to fetch the latests changes into their local copies.
What we want is to avoid this rebasing when the jenkins is broken (red or yellow ball). Instructions are "rebase only if jenkins is green" but... people are lazy  :-)

So, can we do something in the jenkins job so that it blocks the git repo when the execution fails?

Best regards!

Comment: Is Jenkins also managing the GIT repository? Is the git repo running on the same machine as Jenkins? Perhaps look at using Gerrit to manage your shared GIT repo. The Gerrit plugin for Jenkins can be used to automatically verify each code submission. It will be a better mechanism to achieve your desired workflow.http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/

Comment: Nope, Jenkins is not on the same machine as Gerrit/Git. I know what you mean with using Gerrit in that way, but the Jenkins job takes around 2 hours (and it'll take longer), so we cannot launch it on every push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not verifying your commits before merging into your git repository instead verifying them after merged into git in frequent intervals of time.

I think there is no way we can disable git pull other than removing ssh-keys of all users from git repository, which is not feasible. 
We can have a post build step in Jenkins which can manipulate authorized_keys file in Git to block access to git repo. ( I am not sure if it works)

We had a same scenario where each build+verification takes around 2 hours and we can't really enforce this test for each commit. But we were able to manage this situation.

**If you are using gerrit:**

Instead of using Jenkins Gerrit-trigger plugin, we can have our own script which will poll entire gerrit for changes which have all approvals and ready to merge and run your verification. Once verification succeeds all changes in that job will be merged(Submitted in Gerrit) automatically. With this we can avoid bad commits being merged.

**If you are not using gerrit:**

We can  have two separate branches

1. Development branch ( where all developers push their changes)
2. Integration branch (from where developers can pull their changes)

All developers will push their changes to development branch and in frequent intervals we can verify development branch and push changes to integration branch only if verification succeeds.

Comment: Yes, we're using gerrit. We may think on your proposed solution, but I have a question. You say that if the job succeeds, the changes will be merged into GIT, but what about those changes that we're pushed into gerrit while the job was running... will they be merged into Git too?

Comment: Merged into Git means, they'll be submitted in Gerrit. We can still push changes to gerrit while a job is running. Only changes in current job will be merged if job is successful.

Comment: Edited my answer to avoid confusion